# How to enable "multi-lingual" insertion of data for administrators, while having a separate main site language

Tags: website-design, language, internationalisation

Our website allows certain "administrators" to add events and manage those events. Then "users" can enroll said events.

One of the features that is requested is multi-lingual support "on event" level. Which means that administrators can translate their own events for users. Any user (and also administrator) could select the main site language, which is used to display both the event in said language (if provided) as well as main interface.

Now the problem is, how would I allow/make it clear for administrators to insert translations for multiple languages. -- Inserting a translation shouldn't require first changing the main language right?

I could add a "per-field" box to select language, but this would mean that at multiple pages you have to keep changing the language, and the box isn't clear when there are multiple fields on the same page.

As a reference below is one page an administrator might edit:

[image: overview]

Both the description as well as the "gebruiksvoorwaarden" (terms) would be editable. -- And while the main language selected is "dutch", the administrator should(?) be able to add translations also in other languages like french and english.

Where would I put the interface icon for this? Especially considering such fields might also exist on other "tabs" - all tabs without a cog symbol are visible to the end user, and hence the dynamic fields on all those tabs need to be translated as well.

Tot the right of "test-event" bar? But how would I make it clear which field is the interface language, and what is the language you are currently editing as?

Comment: Have you tried anything by your own?

Comment: @Swapna I've tried putting it below the red bar in the top right, but then people get confused which field means what. I've tried putting it next to the input (so with each field) but then people complain a lot about having to set it each time. I've even tried putting it in a separate tab - but then it isn't used and people ask me "where is that feature".

Comment: Sorry to say the explanation is slightly confusing. What are those tabs along with the cogwheel? How your parent page that lists all test events look like. What is ebruiksvoorwaarden on the page? is it part of the description or a separate description all together? What are those empty spaces after the test event? Why your description comes after a huge empty space? What is that table? What is per field thingy you mentioned ?Can you answer these?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added interaction around one suggestion. (If I had understood correctly)

- Mention which page Admin is in. Here Test Event is the page.
- Below have a row of language options. Here admin has the option to edit in the language of their choice.
- On clicking add language, the admin gets to see the options for selecting a language. e.g Dutch here in 02 screens. Admin can select multiple languages in one go as well..
- Once they select something, the language to come as another tab.
- In navbar, change the language from English to Dutch now. Basically show the active state value. Don't give the option to change the language from here as this leads to confusion.
- Give the option to remove the newly added language.

Hope to some extent this would be helpful to you. Feel free to move around language as per the IA as certain sections like cog wheel thing I am unable to understand.

[image: 01]
[image: 02]
[image: 03]
[image: 04]

Comment: Hmm so you suggest the "interface" language to be the same interface language? - Wouldn't that be confusing that if the administrator switches tabs to quickly modify a translation in french he or she suddenly also sees (say) the logout  button change text from logout to "déconnecter"? And It would mean all menus might shuffle around a bit for say arabic (left to right just becomes right to left)? Another problem i haven't touched is that I need to communicate in some way that a field needs to be have a translation in each language if that language is present.

Comment: Where is your log out option ? Please put the screens for each use case. You keep the interface language as it is. Only the editing box languages to be changed not everything else in the screen.

Comment: Will also add putting screen for each use cases where you meant to solve the problem would be helpful. Thanks.